# VSCode - Powershell - Network Drives

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have started using VSCODE for editing and running scripts.
If I run VSCODE as admin, I cannot access files on a network drive (mapped or otherwise).
If I don't run VSCODE as admin I cannot execute the PS scripts I need to.

Has anyone experienced something similar, or found a work around?

Comment: If you run in admin context, drives mapped under your account are not available. This is regardless of VSCode or any other editor. To access network drives you need to supply the credentials when running as admin.

Comment: You may also apply a registry change to allow the mapped drives when running as admin.  https://www.google.com/amp/s/winaero.com/enable-the-access-to-network-drives-from-elevated-apps-running-as-administrator/amp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Administrator account doesn't have the drive mappings your user account has, you can try accessing the **Universal Naming Convention (UNC)** path to the network resources/shares directly.

### Format

```
\\<server-hostname-or-IP>\<share-name>\<directory-name>
```

### Examples

```
\\server1\c$
\\server2\share\foo\bar
```

If you don't know the UNC paths for the mapped drives, run `net use` from a `cmd.exe` prompt under your *user* (**not** admin) account context. The UNC paths fall under the **Remote** column heading in the output, and should resemble the format outlined above.

### Helpful Links

[UNC paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths)
[Net use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/gg651155(v=ws.11))